# How to get the values of an element in order to print them in a new element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of cards with some information about a dealer, I need to set a functionality to edit that info. So, I have a card with info, like: `dealerName` and `cardId`, if you click on that card, a modal should be open with the exact same info of the person, but you can edit that info.

```
export default class DealerChild extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    let dealerInfo;
    if (this.props.dealerData) {
      let dealerProps = this.props.dealerData.dealersData;
      dealerInfo = dealerProps.map((dealer) => {
        return (<div>
              <Card>
                 // THIS IS THE CARD.
                // THIS IS THE INFO THAT CONTAINS THE CURRENT DEALER
                <CardHeader title={dealer.DealerName}
                            subtitle={dealer.CardId} />
              </Card>

              // THIS BUTTON OPENS THE MODAL
              <Button onClick={() => this._openUpdateDealer(dealer)}>

             // THIS IS THE MODAL

              <Dialog
                title="Update Dealer"
                ref="updateRef">
                <div>

          // THESE ARE THE FIELDS TO FILL WITH THE CURRENT INFO OF THE DEALER
                 <TextField ref="DealerNamePopup" />
                 <TextField ref="CardIdPopup" />
               </div>
              </Dialog>
            </div>
          );
      })
    }

    return (<Grid> {dealerInfo} </Grid>);
  }

  _openUpdateDealer = (dealer) => {
    console.log(dealer); // RETURNS THE INFO OF THE CURRENT DEALER
    this.refs.updateRef.show(); // THIS OPENS THE MODAL
    console.log(this.refs.DealerNamePopup); // RETURNS UNDEFINED
  }
}
```

`console.log(dealer);` returns a JSON with the info of the current dealer:

```
{
  DealerName: "Carmen",
  CardId: "23132123"
}
```

please, look at the comments within the code so you can understand step by step what it does.

so, how can I print the info of the current dealer in the modal fields ? which is the exact same info on the card.

**EDIT**

[Here the library I am using, material-ui](http://material-ui.com/#/components/text-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it a bit wrong, I believe. You have a collection that you turn into array of React components. and you create *refs* relative to that single record's component and not the whole *DealerChild* where *_openUpdateDealer* method is. So, in order to get access to those *refs* you could do:

```
dealerInfo[0].refs.DealerNamePopup
```

You either need to add index variable when you create the array of react components and pass it to your `_openUpdateDealer(index, dealer)` and then do `dealerInfo[index].refs.DealerNamePopup`.

Or just create a new React class for these records and move the `_openUpdateDealer` method there.